SQLite3 shows gibberish text (utf8) in different applications
While SQLite administrator (free app) shows my non-English text correctly other applications i.e  SQLite Expert Pro show gibberish text. I verify that my text is encoded with UTF-8. I noticed also that my C++ app does not render the text correctly. What seems to be the problem here?


**** UPDATE ****: The problem also exists in a newly created DB.


Can you share some code? which dll / package are you using for your code? A MRE would be helpful. The only thing, why "SQLite Expert Pro" might act differently to "SQLite administrator" might be the different SQLite Version. (I'm assuming this from the posted screenshots 3.21.0 vs 3.5.1)

@winner_joiner Its quite impossible to share the code right now, but I am wondering.... I used the SQLite Expert to import the questions table as CSV exported from the SQLite administrator. The import was successful and I can see the text in there, BUT now the new db has gibberish text inside the SQLAdministrator and the C++ app. The encoding is still UTF8.  I am thinking of creating a new DB and trying again.

If at least one program is showing the right result, then the DB is most likely OK. Then you have to consider if the application(s) might be at fault. It’s also possible that the data isn’t being stored using UTF-8, but rather using a different encoding.

As for the C++ app: does it render regular non-ASCII text correctly? Do you perhaps need to convert the UTF-8 into a wide character format for the display APIs?

@nneonneo Using SqliteAdministrator my app was compatible with an older version of Windows (before Win10). The problem is that even with the older version of Sqlite (i.e Administrator) I get gibberish without any changes. So the question is how to know that my encoding is not UTF8 even if both administrator apps state that is indeed UTF8? My app is using a pretty old sqlite3.dll version dated from 2006.  I can not understand why those incompatibilities.

You face a mojibake case (example in Python for its universal intelligibility): print( 'Καλημέρα'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1253', 'ignore')) returns ΞΞ±Ξ»Ξ·ΞΌΞ­ΟΞ± …

@mojibake I am still here after 5 hours trying to find a solution. Debugging my app (not a Unicode app just a multibyte setup) I can correctly get the SQLite data select query without problems using the SQLite administrator, which means the text stored inside the DB is not UTF8. Converting to UTF8 i.e using SQLite Expert I get gibberish text inside my app. This is the 1st conclusion.
